# How to get innerHTML value using only class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code similar to following:

```
<span class="subg">100</span>
<span class="subg">10000</span>
<span class="subg">1000000</span>
```

I want to access the inner value of any span using jQuery selectors. So for example if I want to get value of span having value 10000, I do following:

```
$('.subg:contains("10000")').text()
```

This works fine, but if I want to get value 100, then this approach is not correct as I want to get the first span value but since all 3 spans contain 100, all three will be matched.

Another approach I tried is this:

```
$('.subg[innerHTML="100"]')
```

But this doesn't seem to work, as `innerHTML` is not an attribute of span.

**I don't know the order of spans.**

Restrictions:

1. I cannot use loop.
2. I cannot give id.
3. I cannot change `span` to some other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this via class. You'll need to [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the elements that match instead.

```js
function getText(n) {
  return $('.subg').filter(function (i, v) {
    return $(v).text() === n;
  });
}

getText('100').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="subg">100</span>
<span class="subg">10000</span>
<span class="subg">1000000</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` to get targeted `span` value:

```js
var result = $(".subg").filter(function() { return ($(this).text() === '1000000') });   // Change value to get desire result
console.log(result.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="subg">100</span>
<span class="subg">10000</span>
<span class="subg">1000000</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED : I used `filter` to match what you want

```js
$(".subg").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "100";
}).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="subg">10000</span>
<span class="subg">1000000</span>
<span class="subg">100</span>
```

Comment: What happens when the span containing 100 is on second number

Comment: You mean when you re-order spans, so the span containing 100 is in the last and you want to select it ?

Comment: yes. Last, middle any where. I do not know at which place it is going to be. All I know is that I am given a value, could be 1, 10, 100, 1000..., and I have to find which span has the exact value